# Styling span class under list item

Tags: html, css

How do we style span class under list item in css?

I have tried as in below but its not working

```css
wrap.error {
  color: #FF0000;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <span class='error'>Some error</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: where is `wrap` in `wrap.error`?

Comment: why dont you just use `.error` ?

Comment: It won't really work because the `css` style is looking for a `wrap` element with a `.error` class, which you do not have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to apply to all spans,

```css
ol li span {
  color: #FF0000;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <span class='error'>Some error</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

This is to apply to the class only,

```css
ol li .error {
  color: #FF0000;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <span class='error'>Some error</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Follow the order of the children from parent.

Answer (score 3):

style like this

```
li span.error {
    color:#FF0000;
    display:block;
}
```

check with snippet

```css
li span.error {
   color:#FF0000;
   display:block;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>
      <span class='error'>something here</span>
      <h3>What is the smallest prime number?</h3>
      <input type="radio" name="question0" value="A"<?php echo ($question0=='A')? 'checked':''; ?> />2<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question0" value="B"<?php echo ($question0=='B')? 'checked':''; ?> />1<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question0" value="C"<?php echo ($question0=='C')? 'checked':''; ?> />3<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question0" value="D"<?php echo ($question0=='D')? 'checked':''; ?> />4<br>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

***you use `wrap` in selector,but i don't see it in html code.***

*change css styel like this:*

```
li .error {
    color:#FF0000;
    display:block;
}
```

```css
li .error {
    color:#FF0000;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <span class='error'>Some error</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: yes,i missed out the wrap in html code,but this solution still doesn't work.